# Creating a session user login php

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I'm stuck on how to create a session for a user who logs in. I got the part of checking to make sure the log in information corresponds with the database information, but is stuck on how to take the email address and store into a session. Here is my php code below.

```
<?php include '../View/header.php';
session_start();
require('../model/database.php');
$email = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT emailAddress FROM customers WHERE emailAddress ='$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['emailAddress'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to store an e-mail address i.e. the query result into session? (moreover it shouldn't be necessary to fetch the same e-mail address from the database. It's the same as what you're supplying in the `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below.

Please note that this mysql connection type has been depreciated, look up PDO. Also you need to read up on sql injection as this is not safe.

```
<?php 
    //always put session_start() at the top of the file
    session_start();

    include('../View/header.php');
    require ('../model/database.php');

    $email = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];  

    $sql = "SELECT emailAddress FROM customers WHERE emailAddress = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

    if(!$result){
        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['emailAddress'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['emailAddress'];
        $_SESSION['batmansName'] = "Bruce Wayne";
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

?>`
<a href="anotherFile.php">Click to output the contents of our session :)</a>
```

anotherFile.php

```
<?php

    //always put session_start() at the top of the file
    session_start();

    //print out everything that we have stored in the session
    print_r($_SESSION);

    echo "<br /><br />";

    echo "Session email: ".$_SESSION['email']."<br />";
    echo "Batman's real name: ".$_SESSION['batmansName']."<br />";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your header file do any kind of output? If so, you will want to put `session_start` ahead of it so it can set headers. If that's not done, your session data will not be retained.

Next, to store data in a session we use the `$_SESSION` superglobal

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['emailAddress'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. start session before printing any content
2. use $_SESSION to store user-data

Example:

```
session_start();
include '../View/header.php';
require ('../model/database.php');
$email= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];  
$sql    = "SELECT emailAddress FROM customers WHERE emailAddress ='$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $_SESSION['user_address'] = $row['emailAddress'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please read up on SQL-Injections: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection , as **your code has a major security issue**.

Secondly, you'll have to call `session_start();` before you include your header, it won't work if anything has been sent to the browser before you call it.