# How to get user name or details dynamically when click on a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, database

Dear Experts of php and sql . I'm working on a project where there is a table in which two column for "name and having passport".
That table data comes from database. Now what I want that I want to create link on the name of user and when I click on that I get results of those user.
I don't want to write every time a different code.
I want when I click on that link it will get the username and show data acc. to that username. Because there is lots of user . So I want to create a dynamic code that will get username or some unique id and show data acc. to that `

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.green {
    background: #4DDB4D;
    color: black;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");
    $havepassport='';
$sql = "SELECT * from upload WHERE having_passport='yes' OR having_passport='no'";
$result = $conn -> query($sql);
$havepassport='';
 $havepassport .='<table>';
 $havepassport .='<tr>'.'<th>'."Name".'</th>'.'<th>'."Having Passport".'</th>'.'</tr>';


while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $passportClass = $row['having_passport'] == 'yes' ? 'green' : 'red';

    $havepassport .='<tr class='.$passportClass.'>'.'<td>';
    $havepassport .= '<a href=>'. $row['emp_name'].'</a>';
    $havepassport .= '</td>'.'<td>'. $row['having_passport'].'</td>'.'</tr>';
}
    $havepassport.='</table>';
    echo $havepassport;
?>
```

`The output[image: output for above code] of above code is

Comment: can you explain based on expected outcome, that what you want exactly.

Comment: check my image that I attached

Comment: What details fo you want to get when you click on the name? Yes/no? or name?

Comment: I want when I click on link I will get user details from a database But i don't want to write each time a different  code for each user. When I click on link  it will show details form a data base

Comment: let me ask that when you click on link user name append to url or not?

Comment: Like that this when click in that link this link will know to which name we clicked and show data from database acc. to that

Comment: Use sessions, assign a variable to it, and add a clause to `where` such as `AND emp_name = '$session_var'` for an example.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh plz provide me ur no. or maild id I will explain u in brief

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19758672/ as a quick example. Modify to suit. and http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this:
index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.green {
    background: #4DDB4D;
    color: black;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","db_dat");
    $havepassport='';
    $sql = "SELECT * from upload WHERE having_passport='yes' OR having_passport='no'";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    $havepassport='';
    $havepassport .='<table>';
    $havepassport .='<tr>'.'<th>'."Name".'</th>'.'<th>'."Having Passport".'</th>'.'</tr>';


    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $passportClass = $row['having_passport'] == 'yes' ? 'green' : 'red';

        $havepassport .='<tr class='.$passportClass.'>'.'<td>';
        $havepassport .= '<a href="info.php?user='.$row['emp_name'].'">'. $row['emp_name'].'</a>';
        $havepassport .= '</td>'.'<td>'. $row['having_passport'].'</td>'.'</tr>';
    }
    $havepassport.='</table>';
    echo $havepassport;
?>
```

in info.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user'])){
   echo "get infos of user : ".$_GET['user'];
} else {
   // not specified user
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

> Atention! Instead of username put user_id or something uniq of the user.

```
$havepassport .= '<a href="info.php?user='.$row['emp_name'].'">'. $row['emp_name'].'</a>';
```

> info.php?user=[something uniq]

Answer (score 0):

**First Variant**

I think you must wrap name with tag a, for example:

```
<td> <a href="yoursite.com?link=<?php echo $userid; ?>"> <?php echo $name?></a> </td>
```

As you see, when you click to the name your php code will get $_GET['link']. And
you having id of user reload the page with corresponding data.

**Second Variant**

Set a javascript function to a tag`s onclick event. Let this function do XMLHttpRequest. that is all.